# Python iterate through list and re-split items into list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

I have a list that with items that I would like to split again and add as new items in the list.  For example given the below list:

```
pre_songs = ['Totem', 'One, Two, Three', 'Rent', 'Vapors', 'Get Loud > Inspire Strikes Back', 
             'Enceladus', 'Moon Socket', 'Out of This World > Scheme', 'Walk to the Light', 
             'When The Dust Settles', 'Click Lang Echo']
```

I would like to take the "Get Loud > Inspire Strikes Back", and the "Out of This World > Scheme"  Item and split them by the ">" and make "Get Loud", "Inspire Strikes Back", "Out of This World", and "Scheme" as separate items in the list.

I tried using the code below but it doesn't work:

```
pre_setlist = []

for song in pre_songs:
    if song.contains('>'):
        pre_setlist.append(song.split('>'))
    else:
        pre_setlist.append(song)
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work" what doesn't work?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: Well you have you answer here why it doesn't work xD I mean you could have googled it

Comment: You should always include the complete Traceback, formatted as code, in your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `extend`:

```
pre_setlist = []
for song in pre_songs:
    pre_setlist.extend([x.strip() for x in song.split('>')])
```

Shorter, if there is always one space before and after the `>`:

```
pre_setlist = []
for song in pre_songs:
    pre_setlist.extend(song.split(' > '))
```

Result for both version with your example list:

```
>>> pre_setlist
['Totem',
 'One, Two, Three',
 'Rent',
 'Vapors',
 'Get Loud',
 'Inspire Strikes Back',
 'Enceladus',
 'Moon Socket',
 'Out of This World',
 'Scheme',
 'Walk to the Light',
 'When The Dust Settles',
 'Click Lang Echo']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

```
from itertools import chain

pre_setlist = []

for song in pre_songs:
    if '>' in song:
        pre_setlist.append(song.split(' > '))
    else:
        pre_setlist.append([song])

list(chain.from_iterable(pre_setlist))

# ['Totem', 'One, Two, Three', 'Rent', 'Vapors', 'Get Loud',
#  'Inspire Strikes Back', 'Enceladus', 'Moon Socket',
#  'Out of This World', 'Scheme', 'Walk to the Light',
#  'When The Dust Settles', 'Click Lang Echo']
```

This can be written more succinctly as a list comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

pre_setlist = [[song] if '>' not in song \
               else song.split(' > ') for song in pre_songs]

list(chain.from_iterable(pre_setlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pre_songs = ['Totem', 'One, Two, Three', 'Rent', 'Vapors', 'Get Loud > Inspire Strikes Back', 
         'Enceladus', 'Moon Socket', 'Out of This World > Scheme', 'Walk to the Light', 
         'When The Dust Settles', 'Click Lang Echo']
final_songs = [i for b in [c.split(' > ') for c in pre_songs] for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['Totem', 'One, Two, Three', 'Rent', 'Vapors', 'Get Loud', 'Inspire Strikes Back', 'Enceladus', 'Moon Socket', 'Out of This World', 'Scheme', 'Walk to the Light', 'When The Dust Settles', 'Click Lang Echo']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for song in pre_songs:
    if '>' in song:
        pre_setlist.extend(song.split('>'))
    else:
        pre_setlist.append(song)
```

You need to change 2 things

1. `'>' in song` instead of `song.contains('>')`.
2. Use `extend` instead of `append`, since `song.split` gives you a list back